# Error importing Crypto - Tried to update a few modules in React Native and now getting error of crypto

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk, cryptojs

I was trying to update `react-navigation`, and for that I deleted my `node_modules` folder.

But then it was complaining about `crypto`, so I reverted back the changes in my `package.json`, deleted my `package-lock.json`, but unfortunately can't get my old folder of `node_modules` as I deleted it permanently.

Is someone aware how to solve this issue?

Have tried all the possible solutions from [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=While%20trying%20to%20resolve%20module%20%60crypto%60%20from%20file&oq=While%20trying%20to%20resolve%20module%20%60crypto%60%20from%20file&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.447j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) like deleting cache, manually add modules by `--save`, but unfortunately no luck.

```
While trying to resolve module `crypto` from file `/PATH/TO/PROJECT/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js`, the package `/PATH/TO/PROJECT/node_modules/crypto/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/PATH/TO/PROJECT/node_modules/crypto/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `/PATH/TO/PROJECT/node_modules/crypto/index.js(.native||.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)`
  * `/PATH/TO/PROJECT/node_modules/crypto/index.js/index(.native||.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)`
ERROR
10:34
Building JavaScript bundle: error
```

Would really appreciate any help.

I'm using `aws-sdk` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) which I think is using `crypto-js`, and that's what's causing this issue.

Comment: what version of `crypto-js` do you have?

Comment: It's `3.2.0`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **DO NOT USE THIS VERSION! Please, go for a newer version!**
>   It says in the official document.

Please go with the newer version `4.0.0`

`crypto-js` ([npm package](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js))

Comment: I see, let me try